# libGDX: is it better to re-use Screens or create new instances every time?

Tags: java, libgdx

Here's my case.  I have three different types of screens:

1. MainMenuScreen

   - Has a "Start" button for switching to the GameScreen. Also lets player change basic game settings.
2. GameScreen

   - The actual playable game (where the player character runs and jumps).
3. GameOverScreen

   - Screen that plays an animation and then displays a menu that lets the player start the game again (i.e. switch to GameScreen) or return the main menu (i.e. switch to MainMenuScreen).

Am I better off storing my Screens in variables and reusing them when I switch screens, or is it better to dispose of each Screen when I'm done with it and then create a new instance of the screen type I intend to switch to?

And would the answer be different in a case where Screen switching is more frequent (like between an overworld Screen and a battle Screen in a game like Final Fantasy or Pokemon)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you should reuse `Screen`s, which are used frequently and dispose and recreate `Screen`s not used that often.
In your example the `GameScreen`, `GameOverScreen` and `MainMenuScreen` should all be reused, as they are directly connected to each other:
As soon as a player starts a game, it is possible, that he dies. Then the `GameOverScreen` is shown and directly after that the `MainMenuScreen` is shown. So the user does not need to switch to those `Screen`s manually.
The `OptionsScreen` instead, could be disposed and recreated every time, because usualy you open the `OptionScreen` only a few times. Also it is not directly connected to any other `Screen`, but the user needs to "force" the game to open the `OptionScreen`.
But as long as there aren't too many `Screen`s, reusing shouldn't be a problem.
In your second example, the `Screen`s are used even more often, so they definitly should be reused.

**EDIT:**
As @EssEllDee mentioned, you should also make use of `hide()` and `show()`. Those methods get called by Libgdx, when you switch the `Screen` and they can be used to dispose/recreate heavy ressources. For example, you might dispose `Texture`s used for the game, when you switch to the `GameOverScreen` and reload them, when switching to the `GameScreen`.

Comment: In addition to this, make use of the `onHide()` and `onShow()` methods, which get called automatically.

Comment: @EssEllDee you are right. This methods can be used to dispose/recreate "heavy" ressources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Methods are named `hide()` and `show()`, instead of `onHide()` `onShow()`